# Encoding type to stop file (text) from prompting download?

Tags: java, encoding, byte

Here's my situation. If I just create a new text document on my webserver and save via FTP, it shows up fine in my browser when I navigate to it. But when I save the file using my Java application, suddenly when I navigate to it in the browser it makes me download it (open/save dialog). If I resave with FTP, it shows in browser again.

I'm thinking it has to do with the encoding type I'm using when converting String to Bytes, here's my code:

```
public static void turnON(Player player){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("ftp://username:password@host.com/public_html/status.txt");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        byte[] byteArray = "online".getBytes("UTF-16BE");
        out.write(byteArray);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

See where it converts to `UTF-16BE`? Is there a different format that would prevent this?

Comment: Did you try `conn.setContentHandler(..)` with `ContentHadler` as `"text/plain"`?

Comment: If its a plain text file why not use UTF-8. or try UTF-16 (without the BE / LE)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself actually, I just changed the type to `ASCII` after I read over all the various options here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html